# print constraints Gurobi Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, constraints, gurobi

I'm using Gurobi in Python and for a given set `S` I'm adding the constraint as follows:

```
for i in S:
  m.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j] for j in (set(V) - set(S))) >= 2)
```

I want to print these constraints for each value of the sets `S` and `V` on the screen. 
For an example, if `S={1,3,4}` and `V= {1,2,3,4,5,6}`, then, my constraint will be `x[1,2]+x[1,5]+x[1,6]+x[3,2]+x[3,5]+x[3,6]+x[4,2]+x[4,5]+x[4,6]>=2`
I want this constraint to be preinted on the screen.
Can someone please help me to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this.  Your best option is to call `Model.write()` to export the model as an LP file.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide me some more information on this? I searched everywhere, but couldn't find any help forums for this.

Answer (score 6):

use `print (model.display())` after calling `model.optimize()` function.

Else you can also use `model.write(file_path)` as suggested above by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992841/6463137)

Comment: `print(model.display())` is incorrect. `model.display()` already prints, and returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Use model.write("file.lp"). You can choose any name for file but the extension must be lp.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up what the others have mentioned:

---

print to terminal: `print (model.display())`

Produces something like:

[image]

---

save to file: `model.write("file_name.lp")`

Produces something like:

[image]

Where the .lp file can be opened with a text editor.